# $\omega=z^n$ conformal mapping when $n$ is not an integer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conformal-geometry

If $n$ is not an integer, then why is $\omega=z^n$ a conformal mapping when $z\not\in[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Please define what you understand under $z^n$ if $z\in\Bbb C$ and $n$ is not an integer.